# CURRENT_DATE in Spring-data-jpa witout JPQL query

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to write Spring-data-jpa method comparing date to CURRENT_DATE but without writing JPQL @Query ?

I mean something like:

```
public interface EntityDAO extends JpaRepository<Entity, Long> {
  List<Entity> findByDateParamLessThanCurrentDate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be available at this time. There's no mention of it in [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) and experimented with the following but none of them are recognised.

```
findByDateBeforeCurrentDate()
findByDateBeforeToday()
findByDateBeforeNow()
```

It would be very handy. A project I'm currently working on pulls back results where data is greater than CURRENT_DATE in just about every query so I've resorted to using the `@Query` annotation for every one.

I think the best option will be to make a feature request on the projects [Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA/)